# Why did Jessica Jones count three people in her "list" in S02E11?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, jessica-jones

In S02E11 of Jessica Jones, Jessica says "Three and Counting", meaning

> she's killed, three people. First one is Kilgrave, the second one is the prison guard.

Who is the third person?

Answer (score 13):

The third person is Luke's girlfriend from Season 1, whom she killed while under the control of Kilgrave prior to the events of Jessica Jones Season 1.